# How do I write the formula correctly in my comments?

Tags: comments, formula

I want to write this formula in comments:

[image: the formula]

And this is how I wrote the formula in comments:

```
// based on formula S = n/2 * (a + (a*n))
```

However if I'm comparing the comments with the formula then it's missing the `Sn`, `a1` and the `an` part.

My question is: how do I write the formula correctly in my comments?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a multi-line comment in your the code before the function or the code. for example:

```
/*
 *  Formula to calculate sum of n numbers
 *           S = n/2 * (a + l)
 *  where S is the sum of n elements
 *        n is the number of elements
 *        a is the first element in the series
 *        l is the nth element in the series
*/
```